# arm-linux-gnu-gcc collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, fedora

I've installed `gcc-arm-linux-gnu-4.9.1-1.fc20.x86_64` on my Fedora 20 box.

```
$ cat main.c 
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
$ arm-linux-gnu-gcc main.c 
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.
```

Am I missing something? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you encountered an instance of [bug 1122003](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1122003). It seems to have been solved in gcc-arm-linux-gnu-4.9.1-1.1.fc22.x86_64, or you should be able to work around it with the `--with-ld` flag in the meanwhile.

Comment: `--with-ld` is a `./configure` flag, no? It looks like they used `-fuse-ld=bfd` to work around the issue, and this seemed to fix it for me too.  Now on to addressing the `cannot find crt1.o`...